# Spring Boot - introduce wait time when processing request body

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jetty

I have a Spring Boot application with Jetty which accepts incoming requests. Is there any kind of Spring Boot built-in mechanism that can add a lag **between** processing each message (wait 1 sec, process 1 message, wait 1 sec, process 1 message...***no bulk processing***), for example 1 second instead of **TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1)**, not to mention if it's even safe here. Thank you.

```
@RestController 
public class NotificationController {

    @RequestMapping(
            method = RequestMethod.POST,
            consumes = MediaType.TEXT_XML_VALUE)
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
    public void notification(@RequestBody String payload) {
       // handle payload here
    } }
```

Comment: check this link if works for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46177268/java-rest-api-that-needs-to-wait-before-processing

Comment: Why do you need this? If you want to use it in production you can simple add a Filter like @Cyril Beslay answered. Do you need it for tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a Filter (https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-add-filter) that does a Thread.sleep()